# WPF application page doesn't update when I update the content of the labels

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I'm writing a VB.Net WPF application which uses a frame on the MainWindow to show a page that contains multiple labels. I dynamically update those labels in my logic from the page but once those labels are updated, this doesn't reflect in the frame which shows the page.

This is the sub that updates the labels in *Page2.xaml.vb*:

```
Public Sub UpdateLabels(Name As String, microphonefinal As List(Of String))
    Dim labelList As New List(Of Label)
    For i As Integer = 0 To microphonefinal.Count - 1
        For Each Label As Label In Page1Grid.Children
            If Label.Name.Contains(Name) Then
                Label.Content = microphonefinal(i)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

I call the above sub from *MainWindow.xaml.vb* using the following:

```
 Dim form = New Page2

 If microphonefinal.Count > 0 Then
        form.UpdateLabels("Microphones", microphonefinal)
 End If
```

I'm not sure if the issue is because I'm creating a new instance of Page2. But if I don't include this then I get the error: *"Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference"*.

I tried using *frame.Refresh()* to see if this would update the page with the new values in the labels but it doesn't. I've also used *MsgBox* to display the contents of the labels to make sure they've changed.

**Am I doing something wrong? Or is there anything I'm missing? Please let me know if there's anymore information you need to help. Thank you!**

Comment: If you create a new `Page2` for every update then your not updating what your seeing you're just setting properties on a new `Page2`

Comment: Thanks for your reply @JSteward ! i thought that was the issue. How do I get around the "Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference" error message then so I don't have to create a new page every time?

Comment: For that we'd need to see the code that is generating that error.

Comment: This is the code where the error is occuring: 

`If microphonefinal.Count > 0 Then
       Page2.UpdateLabels("Microphones", microphonefinal)
End If`

So the UpdateLabels sub is held in the Page code so it can access the labels. But I'm having trouble calling that Sub without getting the error "Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference". I figured I usually get this error because I've not created the object properly or something. So that's why I tried to create a new instance of the page. But it was obviously wrong to do that. How do I solve this?

@JSteward

Comment: You can't access `Page2` by it's class name you can only access it with the name of  an instance. So it should be something like `myPage2.UpdateLabels(...)` Also, note that this is different than Win Forms wherein each Form has a default instance accessible by class name, e.g `Form1.Text = `

Comment: Okay! That makes sense. So how should I declare `myPage2` so that it references the `Page2` class which enables me to access `UpdateLabels`? @JSteward

Comment: [Here's a tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22927/Multiple-Window-Interface-for-WPF) should be more than enough to get started.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I've had a read through the tutorial but I can't really make much sense of it and how it relates to my issue. I've tried to do some more research into accessing `Page2` through the name of an instance but I keep seeing answers that create a new instance, which isn't what I want to do because it doesn't display the page with the labels...@JSteward

Comment: How do you display `Page2` now?

Comment: Using a Frame on MainWindow which has the source as `Page2.xaml` @JSteward

Comment: That means the frame has content the is `Page2` you can give that a name with `x:Name` and access it in your code behind just like adding and accessing a button or textbox

Comment: So I've given myPage2 as the x:Name `<Page x:Name="myPage2" x:Class="Page2"` and I've tried to use this when calling the sub in Page2 class like this: `myPage2.UpdateLabels("Microphones", microphonefinal)` but it says it's not defined. Am I missing something? Sorry for all the questions. I'm so confused! @JSteward

Comment: Basically you need a reference to the instance of `Page2`. Without seeing an MCVE I can't get more detailed than that. However, [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/getting-started/walkthrough-my-first-wpf-desktop-application) might be appropriate.

Comment: Thanks man! I figured it out. I posted the answer. Not sure if it'll notify you or not so I posted here too. Let me know if you think I should change anything in the answer and I'll edit it :)

Thanks again so much for your help! I really appreciate it @JSteward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to access the sub `UpdateLabels()` of class `Page2` by using the frame as you said. So to call the sub I coded it like this:

```
frame.Content.UpdateLabels("Microphones", microphonefinal)
```